# Python script to make basic file with chromosome information

Tags: python, loops, python-2.6, genetics

I am trying to make some .bed files for genetic analysis. I am a python beginner. The files I want to make should be 3 columns, tab seperated, first column always the same (chromosome number) and 2nd and 3rd columns windows of size 200 starting at zero and ending at end of chromosome. Eg:

```
chr20 0 200
chr20 200 400
chr20 400 600
chr20 600 800
...
```

I have the size of the chromosome so at the moment I am trying to say 'while column 2 < (size of chrom) print line. I have a skeleton of a script but it is not quite working, due to my lack of experience. Here is what I have so far:

```
output = open('/homw/genotyping/wholegenome/Chr20.bed', 'rw') 

column2 = 0
column1 = 0
while column2 < 55268282:
    for line in output:
        column1 = column1 + 0
        column2 = column2 + 100

        print output >> "chr20" + '\t' + str(column1) + '\t' + str(column2)
```

If anyone can fix this simple script so that it does as I described, or writes a better solution that would be really appreciated. I considered making a script that could output all files for 20 chromosomes and chrX but as I need to specify the size of the chromosome I think I'll have to do each file separately.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
step = 200 # change values by this amount
with open('Chr20.bed', 'w') as outfp:
   for val in range(0, 1000, step):  #increment by step, max value 1000
      outfp.write('{0}\t{1:d}\t{2:d}\n'.format('chr20', val, val+step))
```

gives tab delimited output as requested

```
chr20   0   200
chr20   200 400
chr20   400 600
chr20   600 800
chr20   800 1000
```

**Note**: using `with` will automatically close the file for you when you are done, or an exception is encountered.

This gives more information about the [.format()](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) function in case you are curious.

Comment: @are you using Python 2.6? Simple change then, I'll update the answer, but you only need this: `outfp.write('{0} {1:4d} {2:4d}\n'` ...

Comment: I am indeed. Thanks, though how should I first define steps?

Comment: Oh one last thing, how to makethe columns tab delimited?

Comment: @user964689 simply add `\t` between the fields, I'll update the answer for you, all that will change is the last line.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, the script is working and seems to do what I asked. But when I run it as input for a program that needs tab seperated files, it seems not to accept it. I don't know what the problem is as when I open the file it seems tab delimited. Perhaps the ending uses an unaccepted invisible character?

Comment: @user964689 You are not being a pain, I bet it's the additional spaces that are used to line up the output. If you don't mind if the output looks just a bit less lined up, but still tab delimited, the change is easy. The `4d` in the `write` statement should be changed to just `d` .. I'll update the answer accordingly. Let me know if this fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use the `numpy.savetxt` function to save the data to a text file:

```
windows = range(0, 55268282, 200)
numpy.savetxt('Chr20.bed', numpy.transpose((windows[:-1], windows[1:])), fmt=('chr20\t%d\t%d'))
```

Comment: sorry, I have used import numpy as np